# Are computer skills degrading?

Tags: teaching, mathematics

I teach masters level engineering students. I have observed that computer usage skills are slowly and constantly degrading among my students from year to year. Has anybody else observed this kind of effect?

What could I realistically do to combat this problem? I do understand that even if its not my job to do so I need to address the problems somehow. Unfortunately I am getting a bit frustrated to teach students how to graph a function, or numerically find the local minima etc. when i should be talking about formulating multibody dynamics for example.

How do I check that this isn't just a bias that I have somehow accumulated during the years of teaching? I am aware of the it was better in my youth bias. Frankly i dont believe i was much better in most aspects. But I sure knew how to use my computer.

Comment: This is completely anecdotal, but a strong majority of teachers I know at any level have complained to me that the skill and/or maturity level of their students has degraded over time. This could be a sign of our education system slipping as a whole, or a natural tendency for teachers to remember the past with rose-colored glasses, or a combination of the two.

Comment: Degrading from where to where? This seems likely to be closed for being too opinion based, but if you mean from year to year, I think so. We created an entire sequence of what turned out to be very popular courses because new graduate student users of our supercomputers couldn't use them (couldn't code, couldn't script, couldn't debug, didn't understand basic algorithms, etc.). Those of us who manage the systems and had graduate degrees were generally self-taught in the necessary skills.

Comment: @user37208 Yes im aware of this effect im trying to gauge whether im experiencing this or if it is in fact true.

Comment: @BillBarth Unfortunately we are in cost cutting mode so for us less is more.

Comment: @joojaa, oh, we didn't get *paid* to teach these courses, we did it, basically, pro bono.

Comment: [What is it with the kids these days?!?](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/literally-psyched/when-i-was-your-age-or-what-is-it-with-kids-these-days/)

Comment: I could imagine that there is truth to the observation, but I wouldn't know whether there really is evidence to back it up. Of course, @BillBarth and I are from a golden generation that, when we were young, had access to computers but of the kind that had no graphical user interface, not a lot of games, etc, and so had to spend our time figuring stuff out and learn programming. The number of truly skilled programmers from our generation is really outstanding. Whether there is really a decline in skill between people growing up around 2005 or 2010 may be debatable.

Comment: Though it's just my personal opinion, I see no way to combat lax computer aptitude other than to make it integral to everything else that they take time to practice or explore the skills necessary themselves. Since solutions are readily available at everyone's fingertips with the transition from desktop to mobile computing, there's really no incentive other than "you need to know it to move forward," or some kind of self-motivation to just become better at computing.

Comment: And i think that out of the bunch there would be at least a handful who perform at a satisfactory level or higher, and you'll actually find that some circumstance like exposure to hardships while computing, the type of computing these people partake (tablet, desktop?), etc. greatly differs from those who need help with simple tasks. It shouldnt just be your personal bias, just a frameshift in how people are exposed to computers.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth - Every time I read one of the seminal works from the 1960s, 70s, and 80s in CS, part of me wishes that I was alive back then to watch and work with those great minds.  They made it look so easy - I have to remind myself that even Ritchie and Wozniak and Djikstra "stood on the shoulders of giants".

Comment: @tonysdg: Yes, they did. I had no intentions of putting myself or Bill Barth in that category. Both of us grew up in the late 1980s and early 1990s when personal computers were around. Neither of us have accomplishments that come even close to those of the people you cite :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Perhaps, but given that I've grown up in the late 90s and 2000s, and started truly digging into computers in the 2010s, you and Bill Barth are of just as amazing a generation as they were in my mind :) Just saying!

Comment: Maybe you could improve the question by specifying what field you want to teach exactly that would benefit the most from improved computer skills of your students and what computer skill you think are necessary for that.

Comment: IMO, it is the ubiquity of computers that has brought the level of computer skills down. If you got interested in computers in the 1980's you basically were a hobbyist who got in and taught yourself, and if you wanted to do something it required you to write some code or remember a bunch of keystrokes. If you were doing this, you were likely also inclined to select towards STEM. So the people you saw in STEM had above average skills. Now computers are everywhere. Everything is an App, and you don't really get involved in coding, so you aren't challenging yourself to think of solutions,

Comment: @AMR that may be. But as a engineer its not enough to use apps you must be able to see behind the apps and understand what they consist of.

Comment: I think you misread my comment. I am giving a plausible explanation for there being students with far better skills in the past and why you are seeing a degradation in computer skills; your conclusion is not a bias on your part. Another aspect is economic. We have an economy where in order to even have subsistence you need to get advanced degrees in highly technical fields, which many of the people you are seeing today would not have chosen 20 or 30 years ago.

Comment: @AMR Sure, i just commented that that is not enough, unfortunately. The start of the decline nicely coincides with windows 95 so this ease of usability is certainly the source of the problem.

Comment: And there in lies the irony. By the successful engineering of usability and enhanced user interfaces, you have made it more difficult to train a new generation of engineers... By the time you get them, I don't know that there is much you can do. Along the way, if they weren't "indoctrinated" into analytic reasoning and problem solving thinking, it will be very challenging to change the mindset they bring with them.

Comment: @AMR it does apply for other things too. Physical goods today are so well engineered that less and less people think of the internals anymore. Meaning its harder to teach mechanical engineering. Still we know how to teach that, we just dont know how to teach computer use for some reason. Even the CS departments do not, in fact they do more harm than good. Too academic that does not interest people outside CS branches. Not at least without a lot of background understanding on how it might help.